# Opening a SSH connection on Android

Tags: java, android, ssh, jsch

I'm trying to open a SSH connection on Android, but whenever I call the method to excecute the SSH command, the application crashes. I'm calling the method in MainActivity as followed:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>(){
               @Override
               protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                   try {
                         SSH.openSSH();
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   return null;
               }
            }.execute(1);
    }
```

And SSH.openSSH() contains the following:

```
public static void openSSH() throws JSchException, IOException
    {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        jsch.setKnownHosts("known_hosts.txt");

        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect();

        ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");

        String rawData = getData(channelExec);
        String[] data = parseData(rawData);
        setData(data);

        channelExec.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
```

But the error I'm getting is following:

```
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at com.example.raspberrypi.SSH.openSSH(SSH.java:26)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at com.example.raspberrypi.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:19)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at com.example.raspberrypi.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-26 18:07:54.606: E/AndroidRuntime(29704):    ... 4 more
```

Could anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jcraft.jsch.JSch` seems to be a strong hint. Do you have that class in your project?

Comment: Did you add class `com.jcraft.jsch.JSch` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: Seems like I have forgot to do that, I'll try that and see if it helps.

Comment: I added `<uses-library android:name="com.jcraft.jsch.JSch"/>` to `AndroidManifest.xml` file and the jar is under referenced libraries, but now it gives me `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY` error.